# AHK: remap numeric keypad with Numlock On so it behaves like numeric keypad with Numlock Off

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to remap the numeric keypad with Numlock On to behave like the numeric keypad with Numlock Off, including being able to extend the selection with Shift/Ctrl held down.

The problem I have is the following

```
Numpad8::Up
```

Doesn't have correct behaviour when shift+numpad8 is pressed, the cursor moves up, but no text is selected. The following also don't work as I'd like (same behaviour as Numpad::8).

```
+Numpad8::Up
+Numpad8::+Up
```

If I remap a normal key, the selection behaviour is correct when shift is pressed:

```
w::Up
```

Any hints?

The reason I'm doing this is to make a [CoolerMaster QuickFire TK's](http://gaming.coolermaster.com/en/products/keyboards/quickfiretk/) numeric keypad behave like it has a standard numeric keypad layout (I've some registry keyboard remapping happening as well, which is why I want the navigation behaviour with Numlock On).

Comment: The problem is: `Shift + NumlockOnKey` equals `NumlockOffKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's a pain in the ass... compared to normal remapping.

Here is the normal behaviour of the Numpad8-key:

> With numpad on:
>   num8: up
>   shift+num8: mark up
>
> With numpad off:
>   num8: 8
>   shift+num8:up

So if you want to reverse that, what we want is this:

> With numpad on:
>   num8: 8
>   shift+num8:up
>
> With numpad off:
>   num8: up
>   shift+num8: mark up

This is how it could be achived:

```
*NumpadUp:: 
    If GetKeyState("NumLock", "T")
        SendInput, {Shift Down}{Up}
    Else If GetKeyState("Shift")
        SendInput, {Shift Up}{NumpadUp}
    Else
        SendInput, {Shift Up}{Numpad8}
Return


*Numpad8:: 
    If GetKeyState("Shift")
        SendInput, {Shift Down}{NumpadUp}
    Else
        SendInput, {NumpadUp}
Return
```

Now you just need to do the same thing for the other numpad keys that you want to reverse.

Comment: Thanks Forivin, that's great! It didn't occur to me that the keyboard wouldn't have a standard numeric keypad layout.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach that uses a little hack to make it look like the Numpad toggles when pressing the numlock key. But it ensures that the numlock actually is always off and only the numlock light is changed.

```
SetNumLockState, Off
fakeNumlockOn := False
Return

NumLock::
    SetNumLockState, Off
    fakeNumlockOn := !fakeNumlockOn
    SetNumLockLEDs(fakeNumlockOn ? "on" : "off")
    Sleep, 100
    SetNumLockLEDs(fakeNumlockOn ? "on" : "off")
Return

SetNumLockLEDs(state) {
    Loop, 11
        KeyboardLED(2,state,A_Index-1)
}



/*

    Keyboard LED control for AutoHotkey_L
        http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=468000#468000

    KeyboardLED(LEDvalue, "Cmd", Kbd)
        LEDvalue  - ScrollLock=1, NumLock=2, CapsLock=4
        Cmd       - on/off/switch
        Kbd       - index of keyboard (probably 0 or 2)

*/
KeyboardLED(LEDvalue, Cmd, Kbd=0) {
    SetUnicodeStr(fn,"\Device\KeyBoardClass" Kbd)
    h_device := NtCreateFile(fn,0+0x00000100+0x00000080+0x00100000,1,1,0x00000040+0x00000020,0)
    If (Cmd = "switch")  ;switches every LED according to LEDvalue
        KeyLED:= LEDvalue
    If (Cmd = "on")  ;forces all choosen LED's to ON (LEDvalue= 0 ->LED's according to keystate)
        KeyLED:= LEDvalue | (GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") + 2*GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") + 4*GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T"))
    If (Cmd = "off") { ;forces all choosen LED's to OFF (LEDvalue= 0 ->LED's according to keystate)
        LEDvalue := LEDvalue ^ 7
        KeyLED := LEDvalue & (GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") + 2*GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") + 4*GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T"))
    }
    success := DllCall( "DeviceIoControl" ,  "ptr", h_device , "uint", CTL_CODE( 0x0000000b , 2 , 0 , 0  ) , "int*", KeyLED << 16 , "uint", 4 ,  "ptr", 0 , "uint", 0 ,  "ptr*", output_actual ,  "ptr", 0 )
    NtCloseFile(h_device)
    return success
}
CTL_CODE( p_device_type, p_function, p_method, p_access ) {
    return, ( p_device_type << 16 ) | ( p_access << 14 ) | ( p_function << 2 ) | p_method
}
NtCreateFile(ByRef wfilename,desiredaccess,sharemode,createdist,flags,fattribs) {
    VarSetCapacity(objattrib,6*A_PtrSize,0)
    VarSetCapacity(io,2*A_PtrSize,0)
    VarSetCapacity(pus,2*A_PtrSize)
    DllCall("ntdll\RtlInitUnicodeString","ptr",&pus,"ptr",&wfilename)
    NumPut(6*A_PtrSize,objattrib,0)
    NumPut(&pus,objattrib,2*A_PtrSize)
    status:=DllCall("ntdll\ZwCreateFile","ptr*",fh,"UInt",desiredaccess,"ptr",&objattrib ,"ptr",&io,"ptr",0,"UInt",fattribs,"UInt",sharemode,"UInt",createdist ,"UInt",flags,"ptr",0,"UInt",0, "UInt")
    return % fh
}
NtCloseFile(handle) {
    return DllCall("ntdll\ZwClose","ptr",handle)
}
SetUnicodeStr(ByRef out, str_) {
    VarSetCapacity(out,2*StrPut(str_,"utf-16"))
    StrPut(str_,&out,"utf-16")
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. You could use also use that code as the basis of an app to transmit data via the 3 keyboard lights (into an arduino or similar) and bypass corporate USB blocking and/or monitoring :-) I like annoying the security guy at work, thanks.

Comment: Besides the fact that it would be painfully slow, how do you know that the data was transmitted successfully? :p The *lock lights are not very responsive, chances are your data will end up corrupted. You could use your speakers/microphone to transfer data... in theory.  ;)

Comment: There were attacks on modems via the blinkenlights on the front, and that's just two lights, tx/rx. I've got a whole extra bit to play with! You're right though, need to determine max baud rate and probably have some sort of CRC. I guess I might have to move my data extract attempts to the I2C pin on the VGA cable... :-)