# Replace key by dot (".") with Shift Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to replace my `NumpadDot` (gives me `,`) with `.`

But I want to do it so that I have to press shift first.
So `NumpadDot` and `shift` in AHK will give `NumpadDel`

My Script:

```
NumpadDel::
     Send, .
Return
```

This Function returns `:` instead of `.`

Which is due to me holding shift. So what do I need to do to actually `Send` a dot without having any other keys like shift manipulating it to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This Function returns `:` instead of `.`

True that, and kind of weird, because it shouldn't.

Either way, you can use

```
NumpadDel::
      Send, {shift up}.{shift down}
Return
```

Comment: Re: returning `:` instead of `.`. Why shouldn't it? I mean, if OP's `NumpadDot` is giving him `,` instead of `.`, then clearly his keyboard mapping is already unusual (by U.S. standards, anyway). Maybe it's a locale issue?

Comment: @JohnY if by unusual you mean Loki living outside of the states, yes. My keyboard is German and it's got a `,`, too.

Comment: @JohnY unusual because: When `send, .` is executed, a dot should be sent, no matter if shift is held down or not. AHK is pretty strict about that. Try the following: `*a::send .` and press SHIFT+A. `.` will be sent (NO `:`), altough you're holding down shift.

Comment: I have always found the interactions between key modifiers a little quirky in AHK. If I do `+a::send .` (yes, I realize you said `*`, which is more "powerful"), then I can still get a capital `A` by pressing *both* Shift keys and then letting go of one of them, and then pressing `a`. It seems I have somehow activated Caps Lock, even though I naively think I'm only pressing Shift+A by the time I press `a`, which should produce `.`. (If I *hold both* Shift keys when pressing `a`, then I *do* get the `.`.) So, in conjunction with locale, maybe there is some kind of unexpected locking.

Comment: Note that I have not been able to figure out how to reproduce the behavior that you or Loki describe, even if I pretend you are saying `>` instead of `:` (the regular dot key is shifted to `>` on a U.S. keyboard).

Comment: @JohnY very interesting indeed. Honestly, to me the double-shift-problem rather sounds like a bug than intended behaviour. What'd be the point of it.

Comment: Okay,  you might be right then. Probably  I was only able to give a proper solution because I am using the same keyboard layout as OP. :-) another numpad problem of recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504772/ahk-remap-numeric-keypad-with-numlock-on-so-it-behaves-like-numeric-keypad-with similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue Loki, I had `NumpadDot` (not `Del`, because of NumLock) sending me `.` instead of `,` but wish there was an easy way to type a `,` with numerical keypad for some software.

With shift functions I always got a `<`, which is my keyboard's `shift+,` option.

Reading some answers here I tried `*NumpadDot::,` and it didn't work, although it worked with other keys, but strangely enough `*+NumpadDot::,` worked just fine!

... Until I tried in another software (I was typing in StickyNotes), and it actually performs a Del action.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked :

```
Numpaddel::
Sleep, 1000
Send {.}
sleep 10
Return
```

It is going to take one second until the dot is placed but I think that's better than having `:`.

And if you want it without pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> :

```
Numpaddot::
Sleep, 10
Send {.}
sleep 10
Return
```